# Simple MERGE statment not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
MERGE dbo.[table1] target
USING (SELECT [qId], [cId], [deleted] FROM dbo.[table1]
    WHERE [qId] = 1 AND [cId] = 2) source
    ON (target.[qId] = source.[qId] AND target.[cId] = source.[cId])
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.[deleted] = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ([qId], [cId]) VALUES (1, 2);
```

When the `[qId] = 1 AND [cId] = 2` combination exists in `[table1]` the `UPDATE` is performed, however when the combination does not exist, the `INSERT` does not occur.

Comment: the WHERE clause in the source subquery (`WHERE [qId] = 1 AND [cId] = 2`) is an absolute filter - only rows passing that predicate will be seen by the  UPDATE.

Comment: Yes, the UPDATE is not the issue, it's working correctly. The problem is INSERT never firing.

Comment: And it won't; ever; because of the WHERE clause as I described above. I typed UPDATE above but meant MERGE.

Comment: Ok, so how should this be rewritten? I want it to do UPDATE if [qId] = 1 AND [cId] = 2 exists, and INSERT if it doesn't.

Comment: @RadAway You're saying "If x doesn't exist in A, and if x exists in A, add x to A". You need to replace the source query with `(SELECT 1 qId, 2 cId) source` at the most basic. That makes it say "If x doesn't exist in A, add x to A"